# Adding VUE js to an existing Electron App

Tags: vue.js, electron

I have an existing Electron APP with hand coded HTML all over the place and a lot of copy pasted code.

I would like to slowly integrate VUE to reduce the copy pasted components.

All the articles I find assume I use "vue add electron-builder" and start a project from scratch.

How can I add VUE to an existing complete Electron Append migrate 1 component at a time?

Comment: best way to usee add electron-builder if you are not interested into that. so for now there is nothing smiler to that we will let you know if found anything

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way use Electron builder

First you need get a copy from your Vue project.

Run these commands:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli

vue add electron-builder
```

If you need Vue router just run this command:

```
vue add router
```

Your Electron project is ready!